# Google Maps class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Tags: android

when I used this code in XML, [image: is] appear this problem

```
enter code here
```

fragment android:id="@+id/map" 
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: Have you put your API Key in your Manifest & metadata???

Comment: <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyC_hBFxiHyFJMxJdn1mbUSGujdvm96dbrw" />
    </application>

Comment: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="Your_Device Id"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.project_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="Api_Key"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="System_Key"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing a meta tag in the application tag of manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You should use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.

Change

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Change

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
```

hopefully, works perfectly. Best of luck!